# How to specify the datetime format for ros2 logs?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, logging

I read https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Demos/Logging-and-logger-configuration.html#console-output-formatting but it doesn't mention how to specify the datetime format to be something else than seconds, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/e276dc1fe5a0e450e53423ec71d57cbe05b129f8/src/logging.c#L375-L383) for the list of currently supported format tokens  and the respective formatting handler functions.

Wrt. time, the only formats are:

- {time}, which installs a formatting handler [`expand_time_as_seconds`](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/e276dc1fe5a0e450e53423ec71d57cbe05b129f8/src/logging.c#L211-L220) and
- {time_as_nanoseconds}, which installs the formatting handler [`expand_time_as_nanoseconds`](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/e276dc1fe5a0e450e53423ec71d57cbe05b129f8/src/logging.c#L222-L231).

Both of these handlers call [`expand_time()`](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/e276dc1fe5a0e450e53423ec71d57cbe05b129f8/src/logging.c#L180-L209).

So if you want a different formatting, you will have to implement a different handler.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers, with your help I could implement the desired functionality: https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/compare/humble...Kaju-Bubanja:rcutils:humble it is for sure not up to the standards to integrate it with ros, but at least people can adapt it to their use case